Page /api/auth/[...nextauth] does not export a default function in NextAuth with Next.js
I'm encountering an error when using NextAuth with Next.js. The error message I'm receiving is:
"Page /api/auth/[...nextauth] does not export a default function."
Problem Details:
I've followed the NextAuth documentation to set up authentication in my Next.js application. However, when I try to access the authentication endpoint (/api/auth/[...nextauth]), I encounter this error.
// [...nextauth].js file
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

const options = {
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const res = await fetch("/your/endpoint", {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        });
        const user = await res.json();
        if (res.ok && user) {
          return user;
        }
        return null;
      }
    })
  ]
};

export default (req, res) => {
  return NextAuth(req, res, options);
};

I've tried various approaches to resolve the issue, including ensuring that the default export in the [...nextauth].js file is correctly structured.
